# How to use Group By in a Nested Aggregate Case Statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to write a query that shows me an ID column and a custom calculation.

```
Select c.ID,
       CASE
       WHEN m.TYPE='Category 1'
       THEN ROUND((COUNT(c.ID)-sum(m.TICKETS))/COUNT(C.ID),2)
       END Custom_Calc
from   Master_Data M
       inner join Collection_Data C
       on M.CASE__C=C.ID 
group by
       c.ID
```

When I run this query, it produces an error

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

I understand that I would need to include `m.Type` in the `group by` clause but I do not want to see the data at that level. It produces two rows for each `ID`. Ideally, I only want one row per `ID`. I've tried `OVER (PARTITION BY ())` clause as well but it always asks me to group the result by the type which I don't want to. It is important for the calculation.

Can someone help me with this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Turn it inside-out; `count(case when ...)`.

Comment: If I do turn it to SUM(Case WHEN..) Then I still get the ORA-00937: not a single-group group function error

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move the `CASE` expression into the aggregation functions.

It is unclear which aggregation functions you are trying to apply the `m.TYPE='Category 1'` filter to so I have assumed that you are trying to filter all the aggregations:

```sql
Select c.ID,
       ROUND(
         (
           COUNT(CASE WHEN m.TYPE='Category 1' THEN c.ID END)
           - SUM(CASE WHEN m.TYPE='Category 1' THEN m.TICKETS END)
         ) / COUNT(CASE WHEN m.TYPE='Category 1' THEN c.ID END),
         2
       ) AS Custom_Calc
from   Master_Data M
       inner join Collection_Data C
       on M.CASE__C=C.ID 
group by
       c.ID
```